# react hooks with typescript types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to write a custom react hook with useEffect and useState with typescript to get the component props. I want to display the open tasks. I have the following as my props

```
export interface Props {
  lists: List[];
  tasks: Task[];
 }
 export interface List {
  id: string;
  title: string;
 }
 export interface Task {
  id: string;
  ref: string;
  listId: string;
```

I'm pretty new to react but this is how I'm trying to get the props which I doubt is missing something but I'm stuck!

```
type = Hook (TaskID: string) => string// this goes above the props as part of the solution.


    const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
    const [openedTask, setOpenedTask] = useState(null);

     const useTaskId: Hook = (TaskID) => {
     function openTasks(list: Task) {
         setOpenedTask(list.title)
     }

     useEffect(() => {
         URL.subscribeToTaskId(TaskID, openTasks);

         return () => {
             URL.unsubscribeFromTaskId(TaskID, openTasks);
         };
     });

     return openedTask;
 }
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with that approach, What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to be able to display opened tasks from the interface props